# Dynamic two way layout html angular

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrap-4, flexbox

```
<div class ="row">
   <div class ="col-md-6">
     Xyz
   </div>
   <div class ="col-md-6">
     Abc
   </div>
</div>
```

I can easily achieve two layout by doing this but my column elements is in an array

fields = [ 'xyz', 'Abc', 'pqr','stuv' ]

```
<div *ngFor="field of fields">
   <div class ="col-md-6">
     {{field}}
   </div>
</div>
```

**How can I achieve two way layout
In an for loop. Array elements also have different width & height I want it to be responsive enough as array length is not fixed also size of the outer div is not fixed as it depends on number of elements in array**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use CSS [flex](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp).

You HTML code goes as below

```
 <div class="flex-container">
   <div *ngFor="field of fields" class="flex-item">
     {{field}}
   </div>
 </div>
```

The css goes as below

```
.flex-container {
   display: flex;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.flex-item {
   width: 45%;
   margin: 5px;
}
```